# $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is calculable iff $A$ is listable in increasing order

Tags: logic, incompleteness

I am reading A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic by Christopher Leary and Lars Kristiansen. In this [section](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Mathematical_Logic_and_Proof/Book%3A_Friendly_Introduction_to_Mathematical_Logic_(Leary_and_Kristiansen)/05%3A_Syntactic_Incompleteness__Groundwork/5.04%3A_Representable_Functions_and_Computer_Programs), the authors ask to prove that $A\subseteq\mathbb{N}$ is calculable iff $A$ is listable in increasing order.

---

Here are the definitions as given in the book:

A partial function $f : A \subseteq \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ is **calculable** if there is an algorithm or computation that, given input $n \in \mathbb{N}$, does exactly one of the following:
If $f \left( n \right)$ is defined, the algorithm computes the correct value of $f \left( n \right)$, outputs $f \left( n \right)$ and then halts; If $f \left( n \right)$ is not defined, the algorithm runs forever without halting. A set $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ is calculable if its characteristic function, $\chi_S$, is calculable.

A set $A$ is listable if there is a computer program $L$ such that $L$ prints out, in some order or another, the elements of $A$.

---

My attempt:

Suppose that $A$ was listable in increasing order. Then there is a computer program $L$ which prints the elements of $A$ in increasing order. We define an algorithm $P$ in the following way:

Given an input $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $P$ starts the execution of $L$ and

- if $L$ halts before printing $n$, $P$ returns $1$ and halts, else,
- if $L$ prints a number bigger than $n$ but $n$ does not appear in the output, $P$ stops the execution of $L$ and return $1$ and halts, else,
- if $n$ occurs in the output of $L$, $P$ stops the execution of $L$ and returns $0$.

By definition, this program $P$ makes $\chi _ A$ calculable.

I am finding it difficult to prove the other direction. Suppose that there was a program $P$ such that given an input $n\in\mathbb{N}$, if $\chi _A (n)$ is defined then it returns $0$ and halts, else, does not halt.

I am not sure how to do it. If $0$ is not in $A$, $P(0)$ will not halt. Now, I can never know using $P$ whether $0$ is not in $A$. How can I achieve this?

Any hints will be appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't $P$ halt and return $1$ if $n$ is in $A$ and return $0$ if $n$ is not in $A$? Based on the definition of $\chi_A$ given in the previous section and the definition of a calculable function given here.

Comment: @StephenDonovan You're right. I was thinking of semi-calculable functions. I've made the required edits.

Comment: Well now isn't your concern about $P(0)$ not halting moot? This should open a path forward. (also I just realized I had the values backwards, $0$ would be for $n$ in $A$ the way you have it, my bad)

Comment: @StephenDonovan Ah, this was very silly and easy. I was quite confused between "semi-calculable" and "calculable".

Comment: The definitions in the text are confusing (I just wrote and then deleted a long comment because I initially believed they were wrong). The point is that the domain of the characteristic function $\chi_A$ is $\Bbb{N}$, so, if it is "calculable" then there is an algorithm that implements the characteristic function as a total function on $\Bbb{N}$. It's very annoying that the authors invent their own terminology for concepts that are well known under other names: "(partial) recursive function", "recursive set", "recursively enumerable set|".